# How can I solve method POST not allowed error in python Login script?

Tags: python, methods, authentication

I wrote a python script that makes me able to know how many new messages do I have.

First,I want to Login my account.

I executed my script.
But I got this message: "method POST not allowed"

The site URL is:http://miyanali.com
Here is the HTML code of Login form in the site:

```
<form id="loginform" action="loginstudent.php" method="post" style="height:50px" onsubmit="loginme(1053)">

<table style="width:170px;font-size:11px;text-align:right;padding-right:3px;padding-top:2px" cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr>

<td style="width:90px;height:20px">
<input title="username" tabindex="1" style="font-family:tahoma;font-size:12px;width:94px;direction:ltr;background:url(username.png?ldd);border:none;padding:4px;padding-right:21px" name="username" value="" type="text">
</td>
<td rowspan="2"><input tabindex="4" style="font-size:11px;font-family:tahoma;height:44px;width:47px" value=" Login " type="submit"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>
<input title="password" tabindex="2" style="font-family:tahoma;font-size:12px;width:94px;direction:ltr;background:url(password.png?ldd);border:none;padding:4px;padding-right:21px" name="password" id="pass1053" onkeypress="javascript:document.getElementById(&quot;signup&quot;).style.visibility=&quot;hidden&quot;;" type="password">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<div style=";text-align:left">
<a href="/forgetpass.php" style="font-size:11px;">Forgot password?</a>
<button onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;loginform&quot;).action=&quot;/signup.php&quot;;window.location=&quot;/signup.php&quot;" id="signup" style="font-size:11px;font-family:tahoma;width:47px">Sign Up</button>

<input style="font-size:11px;font-family:tahoma" name="passssl" id="passssl1053" value="" type="hidden">


</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

And Here is my Python Codes:

```
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2



cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

# headers
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7')]


urllib2.install_opener(opener)


authentication_url = 'http://www.miyanali.com/loginstudent.php'

# parametersd
payload = {
  'username': 'myusername',
  'password': 'password',
  'passssl': ''
  }

data = urllib.urlencode(payload)


req = urllib2.Request(authentication_url, data)

resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
contents = resp.read()
print contents
```

How can I fix this Error?
Thanks to all of you!

Comment: I am not a javascript expert, but from what I can see, the HTML page contains a function which is called when you submit the fields in the form: `onsubmit="loginme(1053)"`. Instead, you are posting the credentials directly to the `loginstudent.php` page, which does not accept POST requests. Inspect/investigate what the `loginme` function does.

Comment: if the function is available, of course.

Comment: Thanks.Here is javascript codes:

Answer (score 0):

Ok.Here is Login page javascripts:

```
function loginme(rand1){

ssid=get_cookie ( "PHPSESSID" );
pass=document.getElementById("pass"+rand1).value;
document.getElementById("pass"+rand1).value="";
x1=string2Bin(pass);
x2=string2Bin(ssid.substr(0,5));
//alert(x1);
o=xorthis(x1,x2);

//alert(o);
document.getElementById("passssl"+rand1).value=o;
document.getElementById("passssl"+rand1).value=pass;

}




function string2Bin(s) {
 var b = "";
 var last = s.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < last; i++) {
 var d = s.charCodeAt(i);
 if (d < 128)
 b+= dec2Bin(d);
 else {

 upperd=Math.floor(d/256)+210;
 lowerd=d%256+128;
//alert(upperd+"+"+lowerd);
 //document.write(upperd+"<br>");
//document.write(lowerd+"<br>");
//document.write(d+"<br>");
 //b+= dec2Bin(upperd)+dec2Bin(lowerd);
 //var c = s.charAt(i);
 //alert(c + ' is NOT an ASCII character');
 //b[i] = -1;

 b+=s.substr(i,1);
 }
 }
 return b;
 }


function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
  var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );

  if ( results )
    return ( unescape ( results[2] ) );
  else
    return null;
}
```

What should I do in my Python codes?

Comment: You should edit your original post to add this instead of posting it as an answer. StackOverflow is not a forum.